# incompatible types: char[] cannot be converted to CharSequence

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

```
class Word{
    String data;
    boolean search(String key)
    {
        char[] arr=key.toCharArray();
        return data.contains(arr);
    }
}
```

This code I have written must return if the sequence is present in the given String. But it is showing me the below error:

```
Main.java:8: error: incompatible types: char[] cannot be converted to CharSequence
        return data.contains(arr);
                             ^
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `char[]` array does not implement the [`CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) interface, which is what the [`String.contains()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) method takes as input.

You don't need to use the [`String.toCharArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()) method in this example at all.  The [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) type implements the `CharSequence` interface, so you can pass your `key` parameter directly to `contains()`:

```java
class Word{
    String data;
    boolean search(String key)
    {
        return data.contains(key);
    }
}
```